# How to get the location when GPS/LOCATION is turned off?

Tags: android, android-gps

I want to get the Lat/Long of a device when its GPS is turned off.
I tried few tutorials but am not able to get the Location when GPS is off.
Is there any way to do it?? or GPS is compulsory?
Looking for help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can get location using GPS and NETWORK. NEtwork location is approx.

Comment: GPS is not mandatory, you can find the location of a phone using the network provider. Accuracy is just offered up in this instance

Comment: Can I get any instance of it? @Janwilx72

Answer (score 0):

once you have implemented the necessary location code. just add the following

```
Location loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```